# livewire: public variable must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: laravel-livewire

I'm calling the reset() method once.a modal is closed.

One of the public properties is an Object of Class Owner.

I have type hinted it during definition like this:

```
public Owner $owner;
```

In the mount method I also initialised this property

```
$this->owner = Owner::make();
```

Validation etc. works perfectly but when I call the reset method (after closing a modal) I got the following error:

Typed property App\Http\Livewire\CreateOwner::$owner must not be accessed before initialization

I dd-d the $owner variable before calling reset() and it is actually initialized.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, Livewire performs the following when calling `reset`:

```php
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $freshInstance = new static($this->id);

    $this->{$property} = $freshInstance->{$property};
}
```

As you can see, it's retrieving the value of a fresh instance, which in this case, is not initialized.

If you don't need the reset, don't use it. If you do need it, perhaps only pass the properties you want to reset:

```php
$this->reset('name', 'age');
```

If you want to reset everything *but* `$owner`, you can modify the value used by Livewire:

```php
$propertyKeys = array_keys($this->getPublicPropertiesDefinedBySubClass());
$index = array_search('owner', $propertyKeys);
unset($propertyKeys[$index]);
$this->reset($propertyKeys);
```

Last resort is manually resetting the values, but I suppose that's unwanted when resetting something like a form.

Comment: I only need to reset the $owner variable. I also checked the source code in the meantime, it seems that Livewire can not handle typed Objects when it comes to it's reset method. Should be documented accordingly on their site. I skipped the reset method altogether and re-initialized the object by hand.

Comment: Yes that's the best solution in this case